# Change label value permanently in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display a dynamic number which is permanently changed (temperature) on my gui. How can I make my label dynamic?

I tried to set other values but got to know that after mainLoop is called the program is in a infinite state. I have read about the functions .after() but I don't know how to use it exactly, because I don't want to define new functions. I get a returned value and just want that to be updated.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from src import SerialPort as sp

HEIGHT = 300
WIDTH = 500

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

aktTemp = tk.Label(root, text=str(sp.read_current_Temperature())+"°C", fg="red") 
aktTemp.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

sp.read_current_Temperature() - it will return you the current temperature, so I want the label to refresh every second based on this function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the main issue with updating something constantly in tkinter is that for the majority of your program at least, you are locked into the mainloop.

For all intents and purposes, this basically means that in your program, you never actually call the final line, because Python is waiting for the mainloop to end.

The way we get around this is, as you've rightly surmised, is to make use of the `after()` function. If you do not yet know how to use this (and plan to continue using tkinter) you should definitely add it to your toolkit.

---

To start with, I've made a quick change to your program just so that I can get a value returned as the temperature. I did this so that I can demonstrate how you can update the text widget and it involved adding a new function that just returns a random value.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def read_current_Temperature():
    return random.randint(1, 100)

HEIGHT = 300
WIDTH = 500

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

aktTemp = tk.Label(root, text=str(read_current_Temperature())+"°C", fg="red") 
aktTemp.pack()

root.mainloop()

read_current_Temperature()
```

Now, as you see when we run the above, we essentially get the same result as your original program. The temperature is *read* (read: randomly generated) and then the widget is updated and then . . . not much else.

---

So, firstly we need to find where to use `after()`. There are a number of ways that we could do this, but the simplest way (subjectively, in this instance. Where possible I'd advise using a `class` instead but this would require more substantial rewrites) is to add a new function, like the below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def read_current_Temperature():
    return random.randint(1, 100)

def update():
    aktTemp.config(text=str(read_current_Temperature())+"°C")
    aktTemp.after(1000, update)

HEIGHT = 300
WIDTH = 500

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

aktTemp = tk.Label(root, text=str(read_current_Temperature())+"°C", fg="red") 
aktTemp.pack()

update()

root.mainloop()
```

Let's look at this line by line.

---

```
update()
```

The first new line we hit (when running, not when reading) is a call to the new function I've defined, speaking of which . . .

```
def update():
    aktTemp.config(text=str(read_current_Temperature())+"°C")
    aktTemp.after(1000, update)
```

The first line of this function . . .

```
    aktTemp.config(text=str(read_current_Temperature())+"°C")
```

. . . is simply telling the program to go and get the new temperature and assign this as the `text` attribute of the label widget `aktTemp`. This is the line that **actually** makes the change in the GUI.

This line, on the other hand . . .

```
    aktTemp.after(1000, update)
```

. . . is the use of `after` I mentioned above. All this is doing is saying "Every 1000ms, call the function `update()`" which, as we know from above, then updates the label to the new temperature and starts another 1000ms delay before calling itself again.

---

[You can read more about `after()` here.](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)

Comment: In Java I used to write classes. This was necessary. But in Python I did not need it and it works without using class A_Class. Is it important to use classes? I mean I can just access to all of my functions or variables by importing like import Serialport as sp and then accessing with sp.Function() or sp.var.

Comment: Classes are something that I avoided for a long time in Python. But at a certain point (especially with tkinter), I got tired with having to constantly pass variables back and forth to actually make any changes to existing widgets. It's not necessary, but much life `after()` it is something that you should add to your toolkit if you plan to continue with tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, to do this properly, you have to define at least one new function.  I applaud @EthanField's detailed explanation (+1) but here's my alternate implementation using Tk's *tracing* capability:

```
import tkinter as tk
from src import SerialPort as sp

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 300

def refresh_temperature(string):
    temperature.set(string.format(sp.read_current_Temperature()))
    root.after(1000, refresh_temperature, string)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

temperature = tk.StringVar()

aktTemp = tk.Label(root, textvariable=temperature, fg="red")
aktTemp.pack()

refresh_temperature("{} °C")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I will use this implementation. Do I need for all of my variables which I want to update an explicit function like above? And I guess the {} in 
refresh_temperature("{} °C") is something like a placeholder for my refreshed values?

Comment: @ebug38, if your other variables update at the same frequency (once per second) you can add them to the existing `refresh_temperature()` function (renaming it as appropriate.)  If you also need updates at a different frequency, that might  be reason to add another function.  The `"{} °C"` is just a Python 3 `str.format()` format string.